# Объект в Javascript, способы задания

Tags: javascript, объекты

```js
var obj = new Object(key1: 200, key2: 300, key2: 400);
alert(obj['key1']);
```

Почему это неправильно

Comment: где ты увидел такую запись?

Answer (score 7):

Потому что у языка есть некоторые правила, которым нужно следовать.

```js
var obj1 = new Object({key1: 200, key2: 300, key2: 400});
var obj2 = {key1: 200, key2: 300, key2: 400};
console.log(obj1['key1'], obj2['key1']);
```